# White circle reveal search toolbar

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I am trying to add a circular reveal animation to show the search toolbar in my webapp using CSS & JavaScript. I am trying to achieve the same animation as Whatsapp on Android.

[image: demo on whatsapp app]
I managed to make a circle grow animation. If you check the [demo](https://toufic.ml/demo-problem), you'll notice that I specified the circle's final width and height and made the `transform: scale(0.0033) to scale(1)` in order for the circle to not be blurry.
Unfortunately, I am facing some problems:

1. Cannot make the circle grow from the search icon.
2. The back icon and the search input are not showing when the circle expands. I am trying to do this by having a div covering the content and moving to the left at the same time as the circle showing the content.
3. On mobile, the search doesn't grow from the same point as on PC.
4. The circle does not cover the whole toolbar.

I tried a lot of methods and searched all over the internet with no luck. I think that here, professional developers and coders will certainly find better solutions to my problem. This is the

### [DEMO](https://toufic.ml/demo-problem)

website for you to check out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Using it at https://mdcwp.ml. I just used `clip-path`.

Answer (score 2):

it's not so difficult to simulate the whats app search.

Take a look this:

https://jsfiddle.net/pablodarde/9ndp7z3L/

It's possible with a little more code, to reach a better result.

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Whats App</h1>
    <button id='search'>
      <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="input-mask">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #009688;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  font: normal 24px Arial, Verdana;
  color: #fff;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  border: 0;
  background: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
}

.input-mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: -30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all ease .6s;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 60px;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
    const search = document.querySelector('#search');
const input = document.querySelector('.container input');
const inputMask = document.querySelector('.input-mask');

const screenW = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

input.style.width = screenW +'px';

search.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    inputMask.setAttribute('style', 'width: '+ Number(screenW+30) +'px; height: '+ screenW +'px; top: -'+ screenW/2 +'px; padding-top: 30px; right: -3px;');
  input.focus();
});

input.addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
  inputMask.setAttribute('style', 'width: 0; height: 0; top: 30px;');
  input.value = '';
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but it's not the effect I was looking for. I want the search to be on a fixed place and have a circle grow from the search icon. As it gets bigger, it should show the search input with it. In your animation, it's not a circle that grows from the search icon and the search input shouldn't move as the circle grows...

Comment: It would be AWESOME to just fix my issues and use the same framework I used for material design which is [Material Components Web](https://material.io/components/web/)

Comment: Hey @TouficBatache, ok, I understood. I don't know if I can reach the desired effect, but, please, check it out again.

Comment: I reached the desired effect, I just need your help to fix some issues I am facing. The problem is that the search input moves with the white background, I want it to be revealed later. Could you please try fixing the 2 and 4? They are the most important

Comment: Well, I had to set the "input" width element based on the screen width, with this code `input.style.width = screenW +'px';`.

Comment: Could you please edit it so it grows from the search icon and not from the right of the screen?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144158/discussion-between-toufic-batache-and-pablo-darde).